# WooCommerce - Display how many people have a product in their cart with conditional message

Tags: php, session, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using [Show how many people have added a product in their current cart](https://itzmekhokan.wordpress.com/2019/08/06/show-how-many-people-have-added-a-product-in-their-current-cart/) to display how many people have added a product in their current cart on the Shop and Single Product pages; similar to what you see on stores like Etsy.

The snippet works as is but it would be nice to conditionally change the message depending on if there is 1 user vs. multiple people (i.e "1 person has this in their cart right now." vs "10 people have this in their carts right now.").

If anyone has any suggestions on the best way to handle that it would be appreciated. :)

```
function show_no_of_people_added_in_cart(){
    global $wpdb, $product;
    $in_basket = 0;
    $wc_session_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT session_key FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_sessions" );
    $wc_session_keys = wp_list_pluck( $wc_session_data, 'session_key' );
    if( $wc_session_keys ) {
        foreach ( $wc_session_keys as $key => $_customer_id ) { 
            // if you want to skip current viewer cart item in counts or else can remove belows checking
            if( WC()->session->get_customer_id() == $_customer_id ) continue;
            
            $session_contents = WC()->session->get_session( $_customer_id, array() );
            $cart_contents = maybe_unserialize( $session_contents['cart'] );
            if( $cart_contents ){
                foreach ( $cart_contents as $cart_key => $item ) {
                    if( $item['product_id'] == $product->get_id() ) {
                        $in_basket += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if( $in_basket ) 
        echo '<div class="in-basket">' . sprintf( __( '%d people have this in their cart', 'text-domain' ), $in_basket ) . '</div>';

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'show_no_of_people_added_in_cart', 11 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_no_of_people_added_in_cart', 21 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use for this situations function [_n](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_n/)

The code after changing

```
function show_no_of_people_added_in_cart(){
    global $wpdb, $product;
    $in_basket = 0;
    $wc_session_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT session_key FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_sessions" );
    $wc_session_keys = wp_list_pluck( $wc_session_data, 'session_key' );
    if( $wc_session_keys ) {
        foreach ( $wc_session_keys as $key => $_customer_id ) { 
            // if you want to skip current viewer cart item in counts or else can remove belows checking
            if( WC()->session->get_customer_id() == $_customer_id ) continue;
            
            $session_contents = WC()->session->get_session( $_customer_id, array() );
            $cart_contents = maybe_unserialize( $session_contents['cart'] );
            if( $cart_contents ){
                foreach ( $cart_contents as $cart_key => $item ) {
                    if( $item['product_id'] == $product->get_id() ) {
                        $in_basket += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if( $in_basket ) 
        echo '<div class="in-basket">' . sprintf(_n( '%s person have this in their cart', '%s people have this in their cart', $in_basket, 'text-domain' ), number_format_i18n($in_basket ) ) . '</div>';

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'show_no_of_people_added_in_cart', 11 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_no_of_people_added_in_cart', 21 );
```

Comment: That didn't quite work, as the %s didn't get replaced by a number. However, you absolutely put me on the right track with the _n function; thanks!

I was able to get it to work using:

`echo '<div class="in-basket">' . sprintf( _n( '%s person has this in their cart right now.', '%s people have this in their carts right now.', $in_basket, 'text-domain' ), $in_basket ) . '</div>';`

Comment: I'm getting "PHP Notice:  Undefined index: cart" on $cart_contents = maybe_unserialize( $session_contents['cart'] );